# Trying to run example "R on AWS Lambda with Containers"

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am trying to run the example created by MDNEUZERLING of using R on AWS Lambda with containers.
https://mdneuzerling.com/post/r-on-aws-lambda-with-containers/#fn:1

But I am getting the following error when trying to run it locally. [snip of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEvcS.png)

```
07 Mar 2022 15:06:28,046 [INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)
07 Mar 2022 15:06:37,950 [INFO] (rapid) extensionsDisabledByLayer(/opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j) -> stat /opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j: no such file or directory
07 Mar 2022 15:06:37,950 [WARNING] (rapid) Cannot list external agents error=open /opt/extensions: no such file or directory
START RequestId: 8968dd09-4b03-4a0c-8260-202ac927ccb2 Version: $LATEST
Fatal error: cannot open file 'runtime.R': No such file or directory
07 Mar 2022 15:06:37,966 [WARNING] (rapid) First fatal error stored in appctx: Runtime.ExitError
07 Mar 2022 15:06:37,966 [WARNING] (rapid) Process 15(bootstrap) exited: Runtime exited with error: exit status 2
07 Mar 2022 15:06:37,966 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed InvokeID= error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 2
07 Mar 2022 15:06:37,966 [WARNING] (rapid) Reset initiated: ReserveFail
07 Mar 2022 15:06:37,966 [WARNING] (rapid) Cannot list external agents error=open /opt/extensions: no such file or directory
Fatal error: cannot open file 'runtime.R': No such file or directory
07 Mar 2022 15:06:37,982 [WARNING] (rapid) First fatal error stored in appctx: Runtime.ExitError
07 Mar 2022 15:06:37,982 [WARNING] (rapid) Process 30(bootstrap) exited: Runtime exited with error: exit status 2
END RequestId: e7531a2a-1ca7-4975-9841-ff2d0beeeb18
REPORT RequestId: e7531a2a-1ca7-4975-9841-ff2d0beeeb18  Init Duration: 0.23 ms  Duration: 31.98 ms      Billed Duration: 32 ms  Memory Size: 3
```

The query in a separate shell is:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d "{'number': 5}"
```

I believe I am following the example step by step, but doing something wrong somewhere.

My dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:latest

ENV R_VERSION=4.0.3

RUN yum -y install wget

RUN yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
  && wget https://cdn.rstudio.com/r/centos-7/pkgs/R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm \
  && yum -y install R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm \
  && rm R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/"

# System requirements for R packages
RUN yum -y install openssl-devel

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages(c('httr', 'jsonlite', 'logger'), repos = 'https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

#COPY runtime.R functions.R ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

COPY runtime.r ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
COPY functions.r ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
RUN chmod 755 -R ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

RUN printf '#!/bin/sh\ncd $LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT\nRscript runtime.R' > /var/runtime/bootstrap \
  && chmod +x /var/runtime/bootstrap
```

and functions.r file is the following:

```
#' Determine if the given integer is even or odd
#'
#' @param number Integer
#'
#' @return "even" or "odd"
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' parity(3) # odd
#' parity(4) # even
parity <- function(number) {
  list(parity = if (as.integer(number) %% 2 == 0) "even" else "odd")
}

#' A nullary function that returns the current version of R
#'
#' @return character
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' hello()
hello <- function() {
  list(response = paste("Hello from", version$version.string))
}
```

and the 'runtime.R' is the same as:

https://github.com/mdneuzerling/r-on-lambda/blob/main/runtime.R

This is my first time asking here therefore feedback is appreciated. Also I been stuck on this for a few days trying to figure out what is wrong with no luck. Managed to test a python example that works fine, but really need to make it work with R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the docker file. In the following lines

```
COPY runtime.r ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

COPY functions.r ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
```

In the original file this was done as the following,

```
COPY runtime.R functions.R ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
```

This was giving me an error therefore made it into a line for each file to copy, but made the mistake of having the file extension as lower case, this created the issue since the provided image by AWS is looking for the file with upper case R extension (I am guessing this) since the files were saved with lower case extension '.r' .